# Making a POST on next jS api

Tags: next.js, cdn

Im making a post to CDN but i would like to do it with an external API on next js. How will i pass the file that i want from the index?

```
 Axios({
      url: `${url}`,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${auth}`,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      },
      data: formdata
    }).then((res)=> {
      console.log(res)
      toast.success('Success!')
      const file = fileList
      setFileList(file.slice(1))
      setFileName("")
    }).catch((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      toast.error('Something went wrong')
    })
```

this is what im using now for reference